# What is cybersecurity landscape?

Tags: terminology, threats

What does "cybersecurity landscape" mean?
Is it a cyber threat trend?

Comment: Defining a "landscape" is more of an English language concept than a security concept.

Comment: Why isn't this closed yet. The cyber security landscape is just a loose term like "cloud" just used to market stuff. Threat landscape in the other hand is actually a well defined and maintained library of the "most relevant" security risks.